# php popen and php current working directory

Tags: php, popen, chdir

If I use PHP's popen command to execute a script, does is execute it in the context of PHP's current directory?

Currently I am doing something along the lines of

```
popen(' cd PATH; CMD');
```

but can I do it as

```
chdir ('PATH');
popen('CMD');
```

Comment: Test it, you tell us. You're capable of testing to see if your own code works.

Comment: I wish it were that easy, my first code works fine on my local machine, but not on my test server (where it really matters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context in which it's run.

When I use popen() from the command line, it runs in the WD that I ran it from.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r '$h=popen("pwd","r"); print fread($h, 80);'
/home/ghoti
[ghoti@pc ~]$ php -r 'chdir("/tmp"); $h=popen("pwd","r"); print fread($h, 80);'
/tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. I just tested it on Windows 7 with Apache PHP/5.3.2.